# ActiveRecord Query Cache was cleared after saving a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I found the query cache was cleared after i saved a record. do anybody know what's the problem?  Please see the following codes.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.cache do 
  policy_file = FormUnit.find_by_number("F.XXX")

  # @query_cache has a value that is a query of policy_file
  pp ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_variable_get("@query_cache")

  # fetched it from cache
  FormUnit.find_by_number("F.XXX")

  policy_file_branch = policy_file.forms.build(edition: "10/10", effective_date: "2013/1/1")

  # still can fetch it from cache query.
  pp ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_variable_get("@query_cache")
  FormUnit.find_by_number("F.XXX")


  policy_file_branch.save

  # now, @query_cache was empty and had to fetch it in sql query.
  pp ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_variable_get("@query_cache")
  FormUnit.find_by_number("F.XXX")

end
```

Comment: I'm not a particular expert on Rails Caching, but why shouldn't the cache be swept after the underlying data has been modified? Isn't it perfectly fine to invalidate the cache after a change (`policy_file_branch.save`) happened? Otherwise, the cache would return outdated / wrong data, wouldn't it?

Comment: Good opinion. But even if there are no association between policy_file and policy_file_branch, the query cache still was cleared. So I think it should not be for this reason.